# Optional parameters in backticks notation

Tags: julia

When constructing a string it is very simple to include optional parameters:

```
julia> "Hallo $(true ? "Nils" : "")"
"Hallo Nils"
julia> "Hallo $(false ? "Nils" : "")"
"Hallo "
```

However, when trying to apply the same technique to the backticks notation (to run external commands), the following issue arises:

```
julia> `command $(true ? "--flag" : "")`
`command --flag`
julia> `command $(false ? "--flag" : "")`
`command ''`
```

In the latter case the command that I execute will fail, as it interpretates `''` as an invalid parameter.

```
julia> `command $(false ? "--flag" : nothing)`
`command nothing`
```

Also doesn't work, since keyword `nothing` gets translated to text.

Which syntactic options do I have, to use the backticks notation with optional parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an empty array.  Strings will always interpolate to one argument, but arrays expand to a variable number of arguments (including possibly 0 arguments).

```
julia> `command $(false ? "--flag" : [])`
`command`
```